# rendering forms into inherited html take me to the base html page

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django. I've a base HTML page "base.html" in my templates folder which contains a navbar, when I tried to inherit this page to another page that renders a database or forms it's take me back to the "base.html" page.

Here's my base page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>base</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'index' %}">HOME</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">admin</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'my_app:database' %}">database</a>
    </nav>
    {% block content_block %}
     
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

so in the bar a database button where anchor inside this database page , this anchor tag navigate to my **form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% block content_block %}
       <div class='container'>
           <a href="{% url 'my_app:form' %}">Form</a>
       </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

and here's my page where i want to render my form in it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}

   {% block content_body %}
     <form method="POST">
               {{form.as_p}}
               {% csrf_token %} 
               <input type="submit" name='submit'>   
           </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

when I navigate to my form **it's navigate to the home page however the link is how I expected**  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/form/` but it does not show the form it shows the home page
and if I tried to put the  form **directly** in a link inside the navbar buttons it works

**Views.py file**

```
from django.http import request
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,'base.html')

def database(request):
    return render(request,'database/database.html')


def form(request):
    form_context={"form":info()}
  
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=info(request.POST)
        print(form.errors)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()

    return render(request,"form/form.html",context=form_context)
```

**my_app.urls file**

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from myapp import views 

app_name='my_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^form/',views.form,name='form'),
    url(r'^users/',views.user,name='users'),
    url(r'^database/',views.database,name='database')
]
```

**project url file**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp import urls
from myapp import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^data/',include(urls),name='data'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `<!DOCTYPE html>` on every page if you're ingeriting from `base.html`

You problem is that you've called your block `content_block` in your `base` and `content_body` in the page with content, so it's not going to display anything in there ad will look just like your `base.html`

Change `content_body` => `content_block` and it should work.